# Are There Any Other Web Programming Languages That Can Be Used Without A Framework Aside From PHP?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, frameworks

Python needs a framework, so does Java (for the web). I don't know much about Ruby or Coldfusion. But is there another language out there for the web that can stand alone as it is without a need for a framework or without strict adherence to a design pattern (MVC and the likes) aside from PHP? BTW, the statement that Python and Java needs a framework to work with the web came purely from my readings on articles and books; I might be mistaken.

**EDIT** : by frameworks I mean those like Django, Pylon, Spring, JSF, RoR etc

Comment: What, the PHP language alone allows you to do web development, with no library functions?  Impressive...

Comment: I meant frameworks like Ruby on Rails, Django or Spring :)

Comment: The library functions *are* a framework, it just so happens that they're bundled with the language.

Comment: PHP requires a framework: Apache, or IIS, or some other web server. Can't run PHP as a website without one of those.

Comment: @Randolpho I think the term framework is used differently here. And yes, you *can* write a web server in PHP, but I'll spank you if you do. In fact, I have to go... http://nanoweb.si.kz/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think any of those languages "need" a framework. My understanding is that as long as the webserver has a way to talk to the language interpreter you are in business. Hence all the apache modules for the various languages. The framework is just to make common web development tasks (like accessing a database) easier.
You could just as easily write without a framework in any language you can connect with a webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified, a web server is like a function:

```
HttpResponse ProcessRequest(HttpRequest request);
```

And since request and responses both are strings, it's more like:

```
string ProcessRequest(string request);
```

So, any language that can take a string as an argument and return another string should be fully capable of acting as a server side language ;)

Answer (score 0):

Perl does not need one : [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/)

Comment: `mod_anything` has nothing to do with frameworks. You can use a framework without `mod_perl`, you can use `mod_perl` without a framework, you can use a framework and `mod_perl` or you can use no `mod_perl` and no framework.

Answer (score 0):

Python does **not** need one - [**mod_python**](http://www.modpython.org/).

Neither does ruby -  [**mod_ruby**](http://www.modruby.net/en/).

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call those "ways to write code for the web" so much as "ways to write code to embed into httpd".

Answer (score 0):

Check this.
very unconventional..

**[C++ Server Pages](http://www.micronovae.com/CSP.html)**

Comment: It is a programming language. You can talk to it with a web server. You can write server side code for web applications in PostScript if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Python with WSGI (mod_wsgi) and Ruby with Rack (mod_rack) can be used to write web apps, with only a small stub needed to catch the request from the web server.

Answer (score 0):

The last production C program I ever wrote was a cgi app. If you can write web apps in C, you can write them in anything.